# Is there a way to run "nvm use" automatically in a prestart npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, nvm

I would like to have automatically invoked "nvm use" when I run "npm start".
So I come up with this solution:

**package.json file**

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "sh test.sh",
  "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

**.nvmrc file**

```
4
```

**test.sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d ~/.nvm ]
  then
    source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

    nvm use
fi
```

This works and switches between nvm versions console output is:

```
> sh test.sh

Found '/my-user-path/.nvmrc' with version <4>
Now using node v4.2.2 (npm v2.14.7)

> app@1.0.0 start /app-path/
> nodemon index.js
```

But when I call form index.js "console.log(process.versions);" nvm script is executed probably in different process so output is:

```
{ 
  http_parser: '2.6.0',
  node: '5.1.0',
  v8: '4.6.85.31',
  uv: '1.7.5',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '47',
  openssl: '1.0.2d' 
}
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this in a proper way?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23556330/320399

Answer (score 30):

Generally on a Mac, the nvm.sh file is located in your home path. Use the $HOME variable if you have multiple Mac users working on the code.

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm use"
}
```

I would've added this as a comment to the above response, but I'm not allowed :(

Comment: This doesn't work in a prestart script. It has to be in the start script, per @LLeo's answer.

Comment: I had to add `unset PREFIX;` to the start of the command to make it work. thanks!

Comment: @JonathonHill Is that still true today?  No reason to doubt, other than NodeJS/npm evolution

Comment: Similar to @norfeldt, I added `--delete-prefix`. Whole script: `source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm use --delete-prefix`

Answer (score 14):

Your package.json could look like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "source /whereever/located/nvm.sh; nvm use; nodemon index.js"
}
```

To explain. The "start" line is a single shell instance. So you have to have nvm initialize the PATH in that shell instance. Also, `nvm` is a shell function not an executable shell script. The nvm function lives in the shell instance, and is created by sourcing the nvm.sh file.

Sorry for the edits cuz I didn't test my first two.

Comment: Thank you @LLeo. This worked best for me because I was able to create my own script that wouldn't affect my team members since I don't know who has nvm and if it's installed in the same location as everyone else. I didn't test it but by the name, prestart would affect all scripts which is not wanted in my case.

Comment: I did have a question about your answer though. Is using a semicolon equivalent to using double ampersand? `; => &&` I tried both ways and they worked. Just was hoping to understand the differences, if there are any other than aesthetics

Comment: Semicolon is just a command separator in shell. "&&" executes the rest of the line only if the command on the left return "true" which is exit code 0 (non-zero if false).

Comment: Thank you @LLeo. Once again I appreciate your great answers :)

Answer (score 3):

for mac
eg :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm use v14.17.5 && cross-env ENV_TYPE=localhost umi dev"
  },
```

Comment: it seems it calls itself at the end 