# Using nvm in npm scripts to manage node

Tags: node.js, build, version, nvm, npm-scripts

### Background

- I want to make sure that no matter the machine (non-windows) that runs my project it will always run with the same, controlled, version of Node.js.
- I currently use npm scripts for my build, as seen [here](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).
- I want to be able to update and control that version of Node.js, preferably from my package.json.
- I think, but I'm really not at all sure, that nvm is the tool to solve this.
- I've looked into a [few](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) [resources](https://rainsoft.io/install-node-like-a-boss-with-nvm/) on nvm without reaching the understanding I need of nvm to do what I want to. (which may be due to using the wrong tool for my purposes?)

### The Question

What kind of script could I write that would make sure the node version that the remainder of my scripts was run by would be the node version I want?

OR

What tool should I be using instead of nvm? And is there a convenient guide to how to use it for my use case?

### Dream Example

What I hope to do would look something like...

```
"dev":"nvm *Do stuffs?* && npm run restOfDev",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way how to run "nvm use" automatically in "prestart" npm script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301122/is-there-any-way-how-to-run-nvm-use-automatically-in-prestart-npm-script)

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if it's related to what you want, but yarn is very useful to live with problems with package versions. Keeps the package versions in the yarn.lock file.

Comment: We're using yarn for that actually. And I'm very happy with it's performance! I just haven't found a way to use it to lock down node itself yet. Are you using it for that as well?