# -bash: cdk: command not found , after installing AWS CDK

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

I have installed the AWS CDK as per the instructions here : https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk

`npm i -g aws-cdk` ran happily, however when I run `cdk` from the command line the result is

```sh
$ cdk
-bash: cdk: command not found
```

Following the [manual install instructions](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/MANUAL_INSTALLATION.md) did not fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be the node version.
I was using node v10, and it needed to be v12.

I used nvm to change versions

```
nvm use 12.0
```

and now `cdk` works.

Comment: You can automatically change your node version by using a .nvmrc file that specifies it and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378304/5805858)

Comment: Congrats on 10k score 

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - Hey cool!!! Thanks for alerting me to that.  And thanks for the congrats.

Answer (score 0):

if you using Windows 10 powershell check policy and Linux systems :

try again using:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

next try :

```
sudo npm install @aws-cdk/aws-s3 @aws-cdk/aws-lambda
```