# Set node version differently for specific project(folder) via NVM

Tags: node.js, nvm

I know I can change the node version by `nvm use` CLI command. However, I want to set specific node version differently for a certain project(folder). It's changed via `nvm use` command but it's reverted to `default version` whenever I restart the `terminal` or `webstorm` IDE.

How can I set `nvm` remember this different version for a certain project(folder)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use a `.nvmrc` file in the root of the project with the version you want to use. For example `v12.4.0` or `v10.16.0`.
You have to make sure that this version is installed or it will use the default node version in your machine.

Comment: And run `nvm use` to trigger it pick up the version number from .nvmrc

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378304/276311) to automate the node version selection when you change to the project directory on bash.

Answer (score 9):

For example, you want your default `node` version for this project to be `v12`. 
Open your command line in the project root folder, then run `nvm use 12`, then run `node -v > .nvmrc`.
It won't solve your issue completely because you'll anyway have to run `nvm use` just without the version.

Answer (score 4):

### using .zshrc, without always running `nvm use`

**Use case:**

1. If you want to use a different node version for a specific directory.
2. changing into this directory will switch to your desired node version
3. cd out of this directory will switch back to the default node version

### Solution here

1. create a `.nvmrc` file in the desired directory and add your required `<node version>`

> Ex: `18` or `18.1` or `18.3.1` and ensure the specified version is installed on your machine. If 18 is mentioned, any installed version with a major as 18 will be picked.

2. Add below lines to your `.zshrc`

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

nvm_auto_use() {
  local node_version="$(nvm version)"
  local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

  if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
    local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

    if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
      nvm install
    elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
      nvm use
    fi
  elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd nvm_auto_use
nvm_auto_use
```

---

> PS: All the child directories inside the directory with `.nvmrc` also inherit the node version

Comment: Thanks! I needed to add `autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook` to get this working without errors in iTerm 2 (mac)

Answer (score 2):

One more method could be to use [direnv](https://direnv.net/). Create one file `.envrc` at the root of the folder where you want to use a different node version.

For example:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
nvm use <node_version>
```

Then run to allow using of this `.envrc` file.

```
direnv allow
```

- First two lines just load the nvm, for some reason does not pick it up from .zshrc.
- Second line would change the nvm version to the one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I've found that works for me is creating an alias in your terminal of choice, in my case in `.zshrc` so that I can cd into the folder project and change the node version at the same time so I don't forget every time I get to that specific folder to change the node version with `nvm`. The alias looks like that:

```
alias foo='cd ~/route/to/project/folder && nvm use <node_version>'
```