# Is there any reason why NPM doesn't use .nvm if it exists?

Tags: node.js, npm

This gets me all the time.  I check out a project, `npm i` or `npm ci` it and then look at a slew of errors.  I soon realise that it is due to an incorrect node version being used.  But I've been doing this for a while so doesn't take me long; many new to this game would be dumb founded.

If there is a `.nvm` file that specifies the version to be used, is there any reason why NPM can't report on this and in particular if the version being specified is different to that being used?

I know about [run `nvm use` automatically every time there's a .nvmrc file on the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556330/run-nvm-use-automatically-every-time-theres-a-nvmrc-file-on-the-directory).  But my question still stands - is there any reason why npm can't alert you this this?